# Why CSS width property scale the whole image?

Tags: css

This is an example from W3School.

```
<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">
```

[image]
I tried to modify the width from 100px to 300px. Then I found the image not only become wider, but also higher.

[image]

This is the definition from W3School:

> The width property sets or returns the width an element.

I'm a little confused what exactly the width property does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`width`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) property does exactly what it says; denotes the width of the element. But considering the image has no **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** explicitly set, the `height` is automatically adjusted based off of the width to retain the same aspect ratio.

This is because of the **[CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)**:

[image: Box Model]

When not explicitly set, the property **[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)** has a default of `border-box`. And this makes it so that the `height` property is based off of the border area:

> If box-sizing is set to border-box, however, it instead determines the height of the border area.

And the border area is a combination of both `width` and `height`:

> The border area, bounded by the border edge, extends the padding area to include the element's borders. Its dimensions are the border-box width and the border-box height.

Thus, setting a `height` will skew the image and respect the height you set, but omitting it will automatically maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Box-sizing has a default of `content-box`, not `border-box`. But the box-sizing setting makes no difference as to whether the aspect ratio is maintained or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `width` property specifies width of the element. In `<img>` since you have not set any `height` its height is set to `height: auto;` by default which means it will automatically takes the required height to maintain the aspect ratio.

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

The `width Property` will only increase the width. In your example since the `img` tag contain only the width property, the height of the image also get increased when you increase the width.

For example when you assign the `height` property to your `img` tag your confusion can be cleared.